# Calling Flipkart Api in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, api

I am calling flip kart API in asp.net c# .But i got following error : 401 authorization.

I already included flip kart token and affiliate Id in Rest Header as per Prerequisites and category

URL also.So please tell me why i am getting this error. I am Calling RestApi using HttpClientRequest and my asp.net framework is 4.0

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get product category link list by simple 'Get' using URL

```
 https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/<your-affiliate-id>.<json or xml>
```

the response will have list of various categorizes and their url. These urls require HTTP authentication headers (your affiliate-id and access token) in the GET request. You can add like :-

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Fk-Affiliate-Id", "blueskyvic");
wc.Headers.Add("Fk-Affiliate-Token", "your access code");
string res = wc.DownloadString("https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/feeds/blueskyvic/category/v1:6bo-ul6.json?expiresAt=1420832915393&sig=6c1167c0d141bd3edab28f9f2a980a30");//tv_video_accessories
```

The response will have nexturl property which will give you listing of next 50 items in that category.